# how to show comparison in bubble sort in python along with number of swaps

Tags: python, bubble-sort

```
def bubbleSort(arr): 
    n = len(arr) 
    count = 0
  
    # Traverse through all array elements 
    for i in range(n): 
  
        # Last i elements are already in place 
        for j in range(0, n-i-1): 
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1] : 
                count = count + 1
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j] 
    print(count)
  
# Driver code to test above 
arr = [64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11] 
  
bubbleSort(arr) 

print ("Sorted array is:") 
for i in range(len(arr)): 
    print ("%d" %arr[i]),
```

how to show comparison in the following code, the above code displays number of swaps and sorted array

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `bubbleSort` function, you need to print the `count` and the current state of the array either after or before swapping. it's simple just like so:

```
def bubbleSort(arr): 
    n = len(arr)
    count = 0
  
    # Traverse through all array elements 
    for i in range(n): 
  
        # Last i elements are already in place 
        for j in range(0, n-i-1): 
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1] : 
                count = count + 1
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j] 
                print(f"#swaps: {count}, array: {arr}") #<--- just add this
```

And you will get the following output:

```
#swaps: 1, array: [34, 64, 25, 12, 22, 11]
#swaps: 2, array: [34, 25, 64, 12, 22, 11]
#swaps: 3, array: [34, 25, 12, 64, 22, 11]
#swaps: 4, array: [34, 25, 12, 22, 64, 11]
#swaps: 5, array: [34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 64]
#swaps: 6, array: [25, 34, 12, 22, 11, 64]
#swaps: 7, array: [25, 12, 34, 22, 11, 64]
#swaps: 8, array: [25, 12, 22, 34, 11, 64]
#swaps: 9, array: [25, 12, 22, 11, 34, 64]
#swaps: 10, array: [12, 25, 22, 11, 34, 64]
#swaps: 11, array: [12, 22, 25, 11, 34, 64]
#swaps: 12, array: [12, 22, 11, 25, 34, 64]
#swaps: 13, array: [12, 11, 22, 25, 34, 64]
#swaps: 14, array: [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64]
```